# ASP.Net MVC5 Login attempts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, login-attempts

I want to Make **Login attempts** in my **MVC5** project. 
When user Login with wrong Username or password for 5times. With the error message

> "Your Login attempts is over and wait 15minutes to login"

and suspend 15 minutes to login.
I try to google the solutions . All tutorials are use Identity. I don't want to Use **Identity** (actually I really don't know how to start a project with Identity).

Plz link me some tutorials about that or plz let me know the way.

Thanks and respect all!!

Answer (score 0):

Please use SQL Membership provider. It will take care of this task.